# How to put a value of data object in another data object vueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Here is my code:

```js
data () {
  return {
    msg: '',
    rgbValue: '',
    newColor: {
      color: this.msg
    }
  }
}
```

This code doesn't work. I would like to put the value of `msg` in my object `newColor`. Does anyone have a solution?

Here is a complement of code :

```js
data () {
            let msg =  '';
            return {
                msg: msg,
                rgbValue: '',
                newColor: {
                    color: msg
                }
            }
        },
        components: {
            HeaderComponent: require('./HeaderComponent.vue')
        },
        methods: {
            msgFunc: function () {

                colorsRef.push(this.newColor);

                const app = document.querySelector('#app');
                const rgbValueContainer = document.querySelector('.rgb-value');

                if (this.msg[0] !== '#') {
                    this.msg = '#'
                }
                app.style.backgroundColor = this.msg


                function convert(hex) {
                    hex = hex.replace('#', '');

                    const r = parseInt(hex.length == 3 ? hex.slice(0, 1).repeat(2) : hex.slice(0, 2), 16);
                    const g = parseInt(hex.length == 3 ? hex.slice(1, 2).repeat(2) : hex.slice(2, 4), 16);
                    const b = parseInt(hex.length == 3 ? hex.slice(2, 3).repeat(2) : hex.slice(4, 6), 16);

                    return 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';

                }

                this.rgbValue = convert(this.msg)
                rgbValueContainer.style.opacity = '1'

                this.msg = '#'
            }
```

```html
<section class="input-container">
            <label for="inputLabel">Type your HEX color | Click & Press enter</label>
            <input type="text" id="inputLabel" v-model="msg" @change="msgFunc" @click="sharpStr">
        </section>
```

You can see just after msgFunc, the push on my DB, and the problem is here, he push correctly object, but he don't update the value of color

Comment: I'd advice to read about `getters` & `setters`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You won't be able to access data properties like `this.msg` until the `data` method has returned.

Just set that value outside of the `return` statement:

```
data () {
  let msg = '';

  return {
    msg: msg,
    rgbValue: '',
    newColor: {
      color: msg
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you need the `newColor` property to always reflect the value of `this.msg`, you could make it a computed property instead:

```
data () {
  return {
    msg: '',
    rgbValue: '',
  }
},
computed: {
  newColor() {
    return { color: this.msg }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok I understand, but my problem not really solved. 
I use the newColor object for push in my DB run with firebase, he push that object but the color key is empty.

Comment: Why not just push `{ color: this.msg }` when you need to call the database instead of storing `newColor` on your instance?

Comment: Because in the near futur, I add a new key on this object he take a number. 
Else, I'm right with you, with one value it's no use doing an object

Comment: I'm still not seeing the issue. Seems like you could still build that object whenever you are calling the database. You could also use a computed property, but that seems redundant in this case.

Comment: Object is construct, but the value of color is empty, and for example if I write in my input #000, in firebase DB I would like to save it.

Comment: Are you binding `msg` to your input? You haven't shared enough code to help you.

Comment: You're not using a computed in your example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155611/discussion-between-jonathan-and-thanksd).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to set the constant at a top level, and use it to initialize the component data.

Referencing a constant in **the same component**:

```
let myConstant = false;
let app = new Vue({
    data: {
        myDataVariable: myConstant ? "true" : "false";
});
```

Referencing a constant **in a child component**:

```
let myConstant = false;
let app = new Vue({
    data: {
        // Set a data property and user it from your child component as this.$parent.myConstant
        myConstant: myConstant; 
});
let child = new Vue({
    data: {
        myDataVariable: this.$parent.myConstant ? "true" : "false";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I agree with @thanksd's answer that `newColor` should be a computed property, it is still possible to refer to a data variable within the data function if you use a getter.

```js
data () {
  const vm = this;
  return {
    msg: '',
    get newColor () {
      return {
        color: vm.msg
      };
    }
  };
}
```