# Accessing data variables in Vue method for a loop

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, shopware

I want to access the `data()` variables

```
  data () {
    return {
      name: '',
      manufacturerIds: null,
      supplierIds: null,
      categoryIds: null,
      productIds: null,
      minPrice: 100,
      maxPrice: 0,
      priority: 0,
      enable: true,
      active: true,
      minMargin: 0,
      position: 0,
      isLoading: false,
      suppliers: [],
      categories: [],
      manufacturers: []
    }
  },
```

in a method in the same component. I know we can call it individually as property `this.someVariable` but what I want is to loop over all the variables to reset its values. So instead of calling them all one by one, I was thinking to loop over the `data()` and then assign it a null value (to reset).

I already tried `this.data` and `this.getData()` and `this.data()` but neither of them works.

Comment: Why dont you simply put all of them into a variable inside of return then loop over that single variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea to reset the properties one by one because you will need to check each one of them to determine what value you need to set it to (null, array, boolean, etc). Do you really want to have  `if` checks for all the properties?

A better way is to just clone the object **before** you make any changes to it and then just reset all the properties at once:

### Method 1: store reset data locally

```js
data () {
  return {
    // Add a property for storing unchanged data
    defaultData: {},
    
    data: {}
    name: '',
    manufacturerIds: null,
    supplierIds: null,
    categoryIds: null,
    productIds: null,
    minPrice: 100,
    maxPrice: 0,
    priority: 0,
    enable: true,
    active: true,
    minMargin: 0,
    position: 0,
    isLoading: false,
    suppliers: [],
    categories: [],
    manufacturers: []
  }
},
created: {
  // Clone data before you make any changes
  this.cloneData()
},
methods: {
  cloneData () {
    // Method 1 (better way, but requires lodash module)
    const clonedData = lodash.cloneDeep(this.$data)
    // Method 2 (bad choice for complex objects, google "deep clone JS" to learn why)
    const clonedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$data))
    // Store the cloned data
    this.defaultData = clonedData
  },
  resetData () {
    // Reset the values using cloned data
    this.$data = this.defaultData
  }
}
```

### Method 2: store reset data in Vuex store

```js
data () {
  return {
    name: '',
    manufacturerIds: null,
    supplierIds: null,
    categoryIds: null,
    productIds: null,
    minPrice: 100,
    maxPrice: 0,
    priority: 0,
    enable: true,
    active: true,
    minMargin: 0,
    position: 0,
    isLoading: false,
    suppliers: [],
    categories: [],
    manufacturers: []
  }
},
created: {
  // Clone data before you make any changes
  this.cloneData()
},
methods: {
  cloneData () {
    // Method 1 (better way, but requires lodash module)
    const clonedData = lodash.cloneDeep(this.$data)
    // Method 2 (bad choice for complex objects, google "deep clone JS" to learn why)
    const clonedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$data))
    // Set the cloned data object to Vuex store
    this.$store.commit('SET_DEFAULT_DATA ', clonedData)
  },
  resetData () {
    // Reset the values using cloned data
    this.$data = this.$store.state.defaultData
  }
}
```

### store.js

```js
state: {
  defaultData: {}
},
mutations: {
  SET_DEFAULT_DATA (state, value) {
    state.defaultData = value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you made an array of all the proporties in the data-method?
Example:

```
data() {
  name: '',
  manufacturerIds: null,
  supplierIds: null
  dataArray: [name, manufacturerIds, supplierIds]
```

}

and then call a method which loops over dataArray?

Comment: Is this a VueJS? You forgot about question tags. Please add them, otherwise we do not know what language/framework is this.

Comment: Also please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46491468/how-to-put-a-value-of-data-object-in-another-data-object-vuejs
It might be an answer for yours.